# Gitlab CI: Clone repo only before first build in pipeline

Tags: yaml, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have ~5-10 builds in my .yml file for Gitlab CI.  To save time, I'm wondering if there is a way to NOT re-clone the repo between every job.  Ideally, the repo will be cloned once and then all 3 jobs run.  I also don't want to combine the jobs into a single build because I'd like to see the results of each individually (when they are combined, gitlab's "pass/fail" is just the result of the last job).

I don't want to simply do `git fetch` because I want a fresh clone at the start.

```
stages:
  - run

job1:
  stage: run
  script: 
    - pwd
    - make all TEST=job1

job2:
stage: run
script: 
    - pwd
    - make all TEST=job2

job3:
stage: run
script: 
    - pwd
    - make all TEST=job3

...
```

Comment: I came across the same problem, did you find the solution so far?

Comment: I have not found a solution.  As far as I can tell, this is not currently possible.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also fiddling around with this topic.
Actually, I go by doing a checkout-stage at first (with `GIT_STRATEGY: clone`) and then the build-stage with multiple jobs and `GIT_STRATEGY: fetch`.
This ensures that the repo is really full cloned at first and only fetched for every buildstep. Maybe this helps you too.

```
stages:
  - checkout
  - build

checkout:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

  stage: checkout
  script: '@echo Checking out...'

build:commander:
  stage: build
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: fetch  
  script:
    - _Publish.bat commander
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - BuildArtifacts\Commander\**    

build:login:
  stage: build
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: fetch  
  script:
    - _Publish.bat login
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - BuildArtifacts\Login\**    

build:cli:
  stage: build
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: fetch  
  script:
    - _Publish.bat cli
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - BuildArtifacts\Cli\**
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful, assuming you are using a new enough version of gitlab and the runner: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#git-strategy

You can set your git-strategy to none, and manually clone the repo in your before_script section.

This will have some difficulties still - because different runners can service different jobs, if you don't have a dedicated runner for this project, all runners would need access to the repo location.